# Difference between "TOP" and "SAMPLE" in TeraData SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

What is the difference between "TOP" and "SAMPLE" in TeraData SQL? Are they the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [TOP vs SAMPLE](http://datawarehouse.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/teradata-l/top-vs-sample-2474922):

> TOP 10 means "first 10 rows in sorted
>   order". If you don't have an ORDER BY,
>   then by extension it will be
>   interpreted as asking for "ANY 10
>   rows" in any order. The optimizer is
>   free to select the cheapest plan it
>   can find and stop processing as soon
>   as it has found enough rows to return.
>
> If this query is the only thing
>   running on your system, TOP may appear
>   to always give you exactly the same
>   answer, but that behavior is NOT
>   guaranteed.
>
> SAMPLE, as you have observed, does
>   extra processing to try to randomize
>   the result set yet maintain the same
>   approximate distribution. At a very
>   simple level, for example, it could
>   pick a random point at which to start
>   scanning the table and a number of
>   rows to skip between rows that are
>   returned.

Comment: the link is broken(

Comment: @Rocketq That's why it was quoted here :)  Links do tend to break.

Answer (score 4):

‘Sample’ command:

```
Sel * from tablename
sample 100
```

That will give you a sample of 100 different records from the table.
The SAMPLE command will give DIFFERENT results each time you run it.

TOP command:

```
sel top 100 * from tablename;
```

This will give the first 100 rows of the table.
The TOP command will give you THE SAME results each time you run it.