# Teradata sample 1 vs top 1 performance

Tags: sql, teradata

I've been running into an issue where `select top 1 * from x.y` will sit in queue for up to an hour whereas a `select * from x.y sample 1` will run within seconds.  I've been told that it's because `select top` is collecting all the data, sorting it and grabbing the top 1 and `sample 1` is just grabbing a random row, no sorting the data at all, just a random row.

This explanation doesn't makes sense to me especially since I'm not including an order by in the query and the database usage metrics for `sample` are orders of magnitude worse.

| AMPCPUTime | StartTime | FirstStepTime | FirstRespTime | Spool_Usage_GB | TotalIOCount | QueryText |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.92 | 10:57:37.52 | 10:57:37.52 | 10:57:37.92 | 0 | 24248 | select * from x.y sample 1; |
| 0.02 | 9:30:08.39 | 10:57:37.10 | 10:57:37.26 | 0 | 55 | SELECT TOP 1 * FROM x.y; |

### EXPLAIN SELECT TOP 1 * FROM  x.y;

1. First, we lock x.y in TD_MAP1 for read
   on a reserved RowHash to prevent global deadlock.
2. Next, we lock x.y in TD_MAP1 for read.
3. We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step in TD_MAP1 from
   x.y by way of an all-rows scan with no
   residual conditions into Spool 5, which is built locally on the
   AMPs in TD_Map1.  The result rows are put into Spool 1
   (group_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  This step is
   used to retrieve the TOP 1 rows.  One AMP is randomly selected to
   retrieve 1 rows. If this step retrieves less than 1 rows, then
   execute step 4.  The size is estimated with high confidence to be
   1 row (594 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 1 minute
   and 34 seconds.
4. We do an all-AMPs STAT FUNCTION step in TD_MAP1 from
   x.y by way of an all-rows scan with no
   residual conditions into Spool 5 (Last Use), which is
   redistributed by hash code to all AMPs in TD_Map1.  The result
   rows are put into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built locally on
   the AMPs.  This step is used to retrieve the TOP 1 rows.  The size
   is estimated with high confidence to be 1 row (594 bytes).  The
   estimated time for this step is 1 minute and 34 seconds.
5. We do a group-AMP SORT to order Spool 1 (group_amps) by the sort
   key in spool field1.
6. Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
   in processing the request.
   -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
   statement 1.

### EXPLAIN select * from x.y sample 1;

1. First, we lock x.y in TD_MAP1 for read
   on a reserved RowHash to prevent global deadlock.
2. Next, we lock x.y in TD_MAP1 for read.
3. We do an all-AMPs SAMPLING step in TD_MAP1 from
   x.y by way of an all-rows scan with no
   residual conditions into Spool 1 (group_amps), which is built
   locally on the AMPs.  Samples are specified as a number of rows.
   The size of Spool 1 is estimated with high confidence to be 1 row
   (594 bytes).
4. Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
   in processing the request.
   -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of
   statement 1.

Related thread: [Efficiency of top vs. sample in Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709397/efficiency-of-top-vs-sample-in-teradata)

Comment: Take a look at EstProcTime in DBQL. I think you will find the TOP query has a conservative, relatively high cost estimate which is causing it to classify into a workload with a much more restrictive throttle limit (and wait to begin execution). On the other hand, the cost estimate for SAMPLE may be very rough / too low.  Inexact costing for SAMPLE isn't an issue for query planning since there really are no alternative plans to consider. But it can play havoc with workload management.

Comment: As you said, the TOP query was waiting, check `DeferTime` & `DelayTime`. Plus `WDID` to see if they were assigned to different workloads.